# Basic do while loop and if then statement

Tags: vb.net, loops, visual-studio-2012, if-statement

I need help creating this program.
I need to: Write a program to request a positive integer as input and carry out the following algorithm.

- If the number is even, divide it by 2.
- Otherwise, multiply the number by 3 and add 1.
- Repeat this process with the resulting number and continue repeating the process until the number 1 is reached.
- After the number 1 is reached, the program should display how many step were required.

Now I know that my line in the output label is wrong, but not sure how to put number of steps into it.

```
 Private Sub calcButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click

      Dim inputnum, output2, output3 As Integer

      inputnum = inputTextbox.Text

      Do
        If inputnum <> 1 Then
          If inputnum Mod 2 = 0 Then
            resultListbox.Items.Add(output2)
          Else
            resultListbox.Items.Add(output3)
          End If
        End If
        output2 = inputnum / 2
        output3 = ((inputnum / 3) + 1)
      Loop Until inputnum = 1
      outputLabel.Text = "It took " & inputnum & " steps to reach 1."

    End Sub
```

The program does not display any number in the listbox

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, but I really need help asap

Comment: is your problem just getting the number of steps? or are you having other issues.

Comment: It does not display any numbers in the listbox and I cant figure out a variable to determine steps it takes to reach 1.

Comment: You should assign some value to output2 and output3 for the first time add in the listbox.

Comment: you have just created your output2 and output3 variables in your subroutine, they are empty at that time, try moving where you assign the values to output2 and input3 before your inputnum Mod 2 statement

Comment: I just tried, it didnt work.

Comment: Does the number is multiplied or divided by 3?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code, to implement you algorithm, you are not changing the value of the `inputnum` that's why you don't get the output as expected

```
    Dim iterationCount As Integer = 0 '<--- count the number of iteration
    Dim inputnum = inputTextbox.Text '<-- let it be 12
    Do
        If inputnum <> 1 Then
            If inputnum Mod 2 = 0 Then
                inputnum /= 2 '<-- If the number is even, divide it by 2.
                resultListbox.Items.Add(inputnum)
            Else
                inputnum = inputnum / 3 + 1 '<--- Otherwise, multiply the number by 3 and add 1.
                resultListbox.Items.Add(inputnum)
            End If
            iterationCount += 1 '<-- increment the iteration counter
        End If
    Loop Until inputnum = 1
   outputLabel.Text = "It took " & iterationCount & " steps to reach 1."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim inputnum As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    inputnum = inputTextbox.Text
    resultListbox.Items.Clear() 'clear the list for next input number
    While inputnum <> 1
        If inputnum Mod 2 = 0 Then                
            inputnum = inputnum / 2
            resultListbox.Items.Add(inputnum)
        Else
            inputnum = inputnum * 3 + 1
            resultListbox.Items.Add(inputnum)
        End If
        count = count + 1
    End While
    outputLabel1.Text = "It took " & count & " steps to reach 1."
```